# Does String.ToLower() always allocate memory?

Tags: c#, .net, string, lowercase

Does `String.ToLower()` return the same reference (e.g. without allocating any new memory) if all the characters are already lower-case?

Memory allocation is cheap, but running a quick check on zillions of short strings is even cheaper.   Most of the time the input I'm working with is already lower-case, but I want to make it that way if it isn't.

I'm working with C# / .NET in particular, but my curiosity extends to other languages so feel free to answer for your favorite one!

NOTE: Strings *are* immutable but that does not mean a function always has to return a new one, rather it means nothing can change their character content.

Comment: Re your note - indeed; as a trivial example, ToString() doesn't create anything new.

Comment: Microptimization is bad for your health.

Comment: And unhelpful comments are bad for ... ? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I expect so, yes. A quick test agrees (but this is not evidence):

```
string a = "abc", b = a.ToLower();
bool areSame = ReferenceEquals(a, b); // false
```

In general, try to work with **comparers** that do what you want. For example, if you want a case-insensitive dictionary, use one:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, int>(
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Likewise:

```
bool ciEqual = string.Equals("abc", "ABC",
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I agree with your recommendation, but in this case I'm storing a normalized version of some always-ASCII data (not culture related) in addition to comparing it.

Comment: +1 - never knew you can create a dictionary like that. I will definitely use that one!

Comment: @Neil - if you need to store it, then yes: you'll need ToLower() - unless of course you do the normalization on the inbound char[] buffer (probably too much effort).

Answer (score 4):

String is an immutable. String.ToLower() will always return new instance thereby generating another instance on every ToLower() call.

Comment: However due to string interning, it might not actually be a unique string instance if there is already a string that matches that one in memory, right?

Comment: It's possible that the algorithm could check to see if it was already lower case, but a quick look with Reflector makes me think you're right.

Comment: @Jamie - most functions don't check for an interned copy - only very specific ones (or if you call it yourself)

Answer (score 2):

Java implementation of String.toLowerCase() from Sun actually doesn't always allocate new String. It checks if all chars are lowercase, and if so, it returns original string.

Answer (score 1):

[edit]
[Interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_intern_pool) doesn't help -- see the comments to this answer.

Comment: Can you qualify that with an example? If I manually intern it still duplicates: string a = string.Intern("abc");
            bool isSame = ReferenceEquals(a, a.ToLower());

Comment: Try calling that several times in a loop.

Comment: I would expect it to return the interned string. If this doesn't happen I need to go back and update my understanding of interning :(

Comment: I can't get it to return an interned version, even though `a` itself is interned (and equal to the ToString() result).

Comment: Bummer.  I can't mess with it here at work, as .Net 2.0 doesn't have string interning, but I'll try to remember to play with this at home some tonight.  Maybe if I call a.ToLower().Intern(); ...

Comment: I'm thinking about deleting this, but I think the discussion is valuable enough to be worth leaving up, even if it is a bit embarrassing :o

Comment: The main intern consumer is with compiled literals; other than that, you have to call `IsInterned` yourself - and few methods bother (since it takes time to check). Useful for loading grids with alike cells, but you still get a big gen0 hit until the next GC (from the temp/throwaway versions).

Comment: I agree: valuable discussion - nothing to be embarrassed about at all.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found this discussion useful myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following code it will not allocate new memory and it will overwrite the original string (this may or may not be what you want). It expects an ascii string. Expect weird things to occur if you call this on strings returned from functions you do not control.

```
public static unsafe void UnsafeToLower(string asciiString)
{
    fixed (char* pstr = asciiString)
    {
        for(char* p = pstr; *p != 0; ++p)
            *p = (*p > 0x40) && (*p < 0x5b) ? (char)(*p | 0x60) : (*p);
    }
}
```

It takes about 25% as long as ToLowerInvariant and avoids memory allocation.

I would only use something like this if you are doing say 100,000 or more strings regularly inside a tight loop.